# Emgu.cv binding failure in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I'm trying to capture video from camera and display in c# WPF form. But image dont show up when i start the program. Also debugger gives me no exception it's just running. I m debugging and i see the CapturedImage property is taking the data as supposed to be. It might be they work in the different threads. But i cant figure out. So, HELP ME,

I'm binding a ImageSource type property. As you can see,

```
public class VideoCapturing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource capturedImage;
    public ImageSource CapturedImage
    {
        get { return capturedImage;  }
        set { capturedImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("CapturedImage"); }
    }
```

Also capturing code is here,

```
public void run()
    {
        if (cap.capture == null)
        {
            capture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(0);
            CurrentFrame = new Mat();
             
        }
        capture.ImageGrabbed += VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed;
        capture.Start();
       
    }
private void VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e) // runs in worker thread
    {
       capture.Retrieve(CurrentFrame);
       CapturedImage = ImageSourceFromBitmap(CurrentFrame.ToImage<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>().ToBitmap()); 
    } 
} // VideoCapturing class ends.
```

here is the xaml part for binding,

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding CapturedImage}"></Image> 
</Grid>
```

This is the mainwindow.xaml.cs,

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        VideoCapturing VideoCapture = new VideoCapturing();
        this.DataContext = VideoCapture ;
        VideoCapture.run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo when you call `OnPropertyChanged()`. `"CaptureImage"` but it should be `"CapturedImage"`.

```
public ImageSource CapturedImage
{
    get { return capturedImage;  }
    set { capturedImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("CapturedImage"); }
}
```

In `MainWindow` you should call `VideoCapture.run()` instead of `capture.run()`.

Because of `VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed` runs in worker thread you have set `CapturedImage` on UI thread by calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

```
private void VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    capture.Retrieve(CurrentFrame);
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        CapturedImage = ImageSourceFromBitmap(CurrentFrame.ToImage<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>().ToBitmap()); 
    }));
}
```

Comment: It was really good catch. It kinda worked but, now i can get the real bug which is " Must create DependencySource on same Thread as DependencyObject". Can you help me with this.
 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You re the greatest. Thank you with all my heart. I was trying to solve this for days. Apprciate it.